# RLException: [/directory] requires the 'logdir' arg to be set

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, conv-neural-network, ros

i have some problem when i try to run the cnn_bridge in ROS, after i try to figure out there's some message about the warning like:

> RLException: [/home/user/catkin_ws/src/cnn_bridge/launch/segmentation_publisher.launch] requires the 'logdir' arg to be set.
> The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

i dont know the problem and why this is keep coming, am i must to set all the parameter in launch file?

this is the launch file

```
<launch>
  <arg name="source" />
  <arg name="logdir" />
  <arg name="metadata_source" />
  <arg name="mode" />
  <arg name="input_tensor" />
  <arg name="output_tensor" />
  <arg name="display" default="true" />
  <arg name="save_path" default="" />
  <arg name="save_mode" default="0" />
  <arg name="cpu" default="false" />
  <arg name="gpu_percent" default="1.0" />

  <node pkg="cnn_bridge" name="segmentation_bridge" type="cnn_bridge_main.py">
    <param name="source" value="$(dirname /camera/rgb/image_raw)" />
    <param name="logdir" value="$(arg logdir)" />
    <param name="metadata_source" value="$(arg metadata_source)" />
    <param name="mode" value="segmentation" />
    <param name="input_tensor" value="$(arg input_tensor)" />
    <param name="output_tensor" value="$(arg output_tensor)" />
    <param name="display" value="$(arg display)" />
    <param name="save_mode" value="$(arg save_mode)" />
    <param name="save_path" value="$(arg save_path)" />
    <param name="cpu" value="$(arg cpu)" />
    <param name="gpu_percent" value="$(arg gpu_percent)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

tutorial link i use http://wiki.ros.org/cnn_bridge

github package https://github.com/wew84/cnn_bridge

running from:

- ROS Melodic
- Python 2.7 and 3.6
- Tensorflow 2.2.0
- Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

During the launch process of the launch file, the argument is passed as part of the argument

For example:

`roslaunch <package_name> launchFileName.launch **logdir:=***directory_location*`

When it is working, you can add this value by default to the launch file if it is working.